# JS are crashing after jquery load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried to load my content with the jQuery `load` function into `index.html`'s content area. I succeeded with that, but my Javascript isn't working. I want to call it on each click of my menu's elements. Is it possible?

[click here to see the page](http://unidef.com.tr/fresh/)

menu:

```
<div id="nav" class="section group">
    <div id="menu" class="col span_9_of_12">
        <ul id="navmenu">
            <li><a href="content/aboutme.html">Hakkımda</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/portfolio.html">Portfolyo</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/contact.html">İletişim</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/photos.html">Fotoğraflar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

load function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#content').load($('#navmenu li a:last').attr('href'));

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('#navmenu li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

$('#navmenu li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').hide('slow',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show('slow',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('slow');
    }
    return false;

});

});
```

Comment: Can you post your ajax call? and other code? most probably is that after ajax call you need to call the js function or use event delegation

Comment: Try using `async: false` as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6251288/1085891) suggests. Maybe the second load requires the first load call to finish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE: My original answer no longer applies. OP changed the page implementation and question completely since I answered.

But as I stated in a comment below, The [easytabs documentation](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/) states that the tab element and the panel divs must all be inside the container div.

```
<div id="tab-container" class="tab-container">
    <ul class='etabs'>
        <li class='tab'><a href="#hakkimda">Hakkımda</a></li>
        <li class='tab'><a href="#portfolyo">Portfolyo</a></li>
        <li class='tab'><a href="#fotograflar">Fotoğraflar</a></li>
        <li class='tab'><a href="#iletisim">İletişim</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="hakkimda">
    ...
    </div>
    <div id="portfolyo">
    ...
    </div>
    <div id="iletisim">
    ...
    </div>
    <div id="fotograflar">
    ...
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: it is still crashing and I changed my method. this time not call with ajax. I include everything in index.html and try to show with jquery tabs. but still crashing.......... T_T

Comment: @android93 - Did the changes I suggested not work? As for the tabs, you need to look over the [documentation](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/). It sounds like you must place the `<ul class="tabs">` element inside the `<div id="tab-container" class="tab-container">` element in order for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than adding script inline, do this

```
$( "#jqc_content" ).load( "content/aboutme.html", function() {
   carouselfn(); // call your carousel invocation function here
});
```

From [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Callback Function

If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed

Comment: thanks for the advice but still I face with the same problem, I also add the carousel function code in my question.

Comment: Can you move this $("#jqc_content").load("content/aboutme.html", to some common scrpt, you have included this in the same container that will replace it completely

Comment: I added it to one of my common script but this time it is not load the aboutme page.

Comment: There are lot of error in console carouFredSel: No element found for "#thumbscarousel". If you run this function $( "#jqc_content" ).load( "content/aboutme.html", function() {
   carouselfn(); // call your carousel invocation function here
}); in console of homepage it works fine, soem of your javascript is not working fine

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it finally. It's all about the html structure.